# Probability of sources agreeing given historical instances of agreement and disagreement.

Tags: probability

How can I compute the probability of sources agreeing given a historical record of agreements and disagreements between the sources?

Taken a step further: How can I compute the probability of a source agreeing given a set of sources that agree and the historical record?

**Illustrative Example**

You're observing a classroom with 3 students $s_1, s_2, s_3$. The students will answer 3 questions $q_1, q_2, q_3$.

You notice $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on $q_1$.

You notice $s_2$ and $s_3$ agree on $q_2$.

You notice $s_1$ and $s_3$ disagree on $q_3$.

1. Based off your observations, what is the probability that $s_1$ and $s_3$ agree on a new question $q_{new}$?
2. If $s_1$ and $s_2$ agree on $q_{new}$, what is the probability that $s_3$ also agrees?

Comment: We probably need some more information on the priors for the answers, and what "you" actually notice.  On the first question, do you know only that $s_1$ and $s_2$ give the same answer, or do you actually know which answers they give, and then notice that those answers happen to be the same?

Comment: You know what each student answered. For the actual application, the answers could a number, a class (e.g. "yes" or "no") or a set of classifications (e.g. {"furry","dog"}). The questions are unrelated except that the type and/or universe of classes of the answer is the same.

I understand some assumptions may need to be made to obtain an answer. I'm hoping to learn these assumptions as well as the solution they may lead to.

Comment: It's okay to assume that students cannot guess the same answer. There is no "randomness" in their choice.

Comment: Where does $q_{new}$ come into play? (i.e. how is it connected to $q_1$, $q_2$ and $q_3$? In basic terms, if the first three questions were about maths, and the next one is about history (but all of them say have the same "universe of answers" of just numbers from 1 to 2018), the first three questions really don't tell me much)

Comment: The questions are of the same type and the student applies the same model/knowledge they used for prior questions. So if $q_1, q_2, q_3$ are about math, $q_{new}$ is also about math. Should we assume something like "there are $k$ possible answers to any question"?

Comment: In the real-world application, there are thousands of sources and hundreds of thousands of agreements/disagreements. I'm curious if that would dramatically change the approach, probably best left to another question :)